# Number of Zero-crossings - Equation

Tags: math, signal-processing, equation, speech, wave

I have written an algorithm that calculates the number of zero-crossings within a signal. By this, I mean the number of times a value changes from + to - and vice-versa.

The algorithm is explained like this:

If there are the following elements:

```
v1 = {90, -4, -3, 1, 3}
```

Then you multiply the value by the value next to it. (i * i+1)

Then taking the sign value sign(val) determine if this is positive or negative. Example:

```
e1 = {90 * -4} = -360 -> sigum(e1) = -1 
e2 = {-4 * -3} =  12  -> signum(e2) = 1
e3 = {-3 *  1} =  -3  -> signum(e3) = -1
e4 = {1 *   3} =  3   -> signum(e4) = 1
```

Therefore the total number of values changed from negative to positive is = 2 ..

Now I want to put this forumular, algorithm into an equation so that I can present it.

I have asked a simular question, but got really confused so went away and thought about it and came up with (what I think the equation should look like).. It's probably wrong, well, laughably wrong. But here it is:

[image]

Now the logic behind it:

I pass in a V (val)

I get the absolute value of the summation of the signum from calculating (Vi * Vi+1) .. The signum(Vi * Vi+1) should produce -1, 1, ..., values

If and only if the value is -1 (Because I'm only interested in the number of times zero is crossed, therefore, the zero values.

Does this look correct, if not, can anyone suggest improvements?

Thank you :)!

EDIT:

[image]

Is this correct now?

Comment: Honestly, this really is not a programming question is it? If you are asking for an algorithm that will give you the answer, that is fine, but just asking for mathematical expression in this case has nothing really to do with programming and there does not really belong on stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing the right thing here but your equation is wrong simply because you only want to count the sign of the product of adjacent elements when it is negative. Dont sum the sign of products since positive sign products should be neglected. For this reason, an explicit mathematical formula is tricky as positive products between adjacent elements should be ignored. What you want is a function that takes 2 arguments and evaluates to 1 when their product is negative and zero when non-negative

```
f(x,y) = 1 if xy < 0
       = 0 otherwise
```

then your number of crossing points is simply given by

```
sum(f(v1[i],v1[i+1])) for i = 0 to i = n-1
```

where `n` is the length of your vector/array `v1` (using C style array access notation based on zero indexing). You also have to consider edge conditions such as 4 consecutive points {-1,0,0,1} - do you want to consider this as simply one zero crossing or 2??? Only you can answer this based on the specifics of your problem, but whatever your answer adjust your algorithm accordingly.

Comment: are you saying the function can be represented as an equation? I'm confused.. I know the algorithm is correct, I just don't know whether the equation that I've written to represent it is correct?

Comment: I would say the equation is wrong since you are negating valid zero crossings with non-zero crossings (which have sign +1). See my updated answer

Comment: @Phorce you are summing SIGN of product of adjacent elements. Thus for a vector [-1,1,2,3] your formula results in the number of crossing points as 2 (-1 + 1 + 1) which is wrong. It should be -1. Your formula should consider products that have positive sign as having a zero weight

Comment: I get what you mean now (Sorry, this has been frustrating me for ages) So what I could simply do is, calculate the SIGN of the product first, once I have that, check to see if the value is -1 and if this is true, sum up the elements that are -1?

Comment: @Phorce that is what I am trying to say - if the sign is negative, count it as a crossing and add it to your count. If it is positive, totally ignore it. If you look at my formula in my answer, you will see this evaluates to exactly the same thing

Comment: Yeah, I get that now! BUT, I don't know how to represent that process in an equation format.. That's what I need help with.

Comment: @Phorce And that is what my answer gives you - sum the value of the function `f(v[i],v[i+1])` (as defined in my answer) from i = 0 to (n-1). I dont know how to make it any more clear

Comment: I get the process and the formula.. So would something like this be sufficient enough? ∑i(1−sgn(ViVi+1))/2 - Thank you though :)

Comment: @Phorce Using `sgn` is not the way to go as you must **ignore positive values of sgn**. The function `f` in my answer (it is a perfectly valid function of 2 variables) is the function you are looking for, not `sgn`

Comment: I think I got it!! Please can you check my edit in my post to see if this matches to what you were saying

Comment: @Phorce I do not understand the meaning of the right arrow in your function notation. But the ZC part looks right if you can fix the `f` part - take a look at this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function for now to define `f`

Comment: I have updated the equation (in my original post) I think this is right now, I hope it is anyway!

Comment: @Phorce Dont forget to deal with = 0 too - as it stands your function is undefined for x == y == 0

Comment: But what should this value return, if such things should happen?

Comment: @Phorce That is for you to decide. Consider this case though - the set of points [-1,0,1,0,-1]. For this vector calculate what happens to the number of crossing points if you dont deal with the xy == 0