# Options for detecting zero cross of audio

Tags: c++, c, zero

I have live audio coming in and I need to detect zero crossings.

The simpler algorithm to do this, like stated by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504019/number-of-zero-crossings-equation) is not acceptable for what I need. This algorithm detects a zero crossing by taking the sign of the multiplication of the current item with the previous one.

This is a simple example of this method failing:

> -1, -0.5, 0, 0, 0.32, 0.5...

Two zeros in a row and the algorithm will fail.

This method is implemented by this:

```
int sign(float value) {
  if (value < 0) {
    return -1;
  } else if (value > 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

for (int i=0; i<numFrames-1; i++) {
    int signR = sign(data[i+1] * data[i]);        
    if (signR == 0) printf("zero cross");
    // but this will fail for data[i+1] = data[i] = 0, for example

}
```

What other options of algorithms do I have to detect zero crossings?

Comment: Just keep track of the sign of the last non-zero sample. If the sign changes, you have a zero crossing.

Comment: Be aware that floating point values are rarely equal to zero.  You should compare against an *epsilon* or tolerance value, such as 1E-06; anything less than this value is considered zero.

Comment: I did that and I ended with a bunch of zeros in a row, making it impossible to detect zero crossing.

Comment: You may want to consider using Fixed Point math to get better accuracy.

Comment: It would be interesting to know *why* you want to detect zero crossings. One reason is that's a good time to switch output routes, to avoid a sudden level change. If so that can be done when the signal is near zero, rather than when crossing.

Comment: An audio signal crosses zero thousands of times per second (twice the highest frequency in Hz).  It will be very difficult to get timing right for anything but the lowest frequency sounds.  It's better to switch outputs during a period of silence - a large number of identical (ideally zero, but not always) samples in a row.

Comment: Another thing to think about: A DC offset in your signal - being the signal not centered on zero - will throw a monkey wrench into all of these calculations.  Does it "count" if the signal drops from 0.4 to 0.1, and then starts going back up?  What if the signal never crosses zero?

Comment: if you have an unsigned integer representation, you will never cross zero...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore the value and only use the sign to detect crossing.

```
#include <math.h>

for (int i=0; i<numFrames-1; i++) {
  if (signbit(data[i+1]) != signbit(data[i])) printf("zero cross");
}
```

> The signbit macro reports the sign of all values, including infinities, zeros, and NaNs.

[Edit]

`signbit()` returns a nonzero value if and only if the sign of its argument value is negative.  So it is possible that 2 different negative values may return different nonzero values.  Better to use:

```
  if (!signbit(data[i+1]) != !signbit(data[i])) printf("zero cross");
```

Answer (score 2):

Keep record of the sign of last non-zero sample and only consider the result of the multiplication if the current sample is non-zero as well (zero samples are never crossings themselves).

```
for (int i=0, previous=sign(data[0]); i<numFrames-1; i++) {
    if(int current = sign(data[i])) {
        if(sign(previous * current) == -1)
            printf("zero cross");
        previous = current;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I understand that this method is better than the other one, but suppose there are a lots of zeros in the middle, like -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 and it will detect a zero cross on the last 1, but a lot of time passed and the wave may be out of phase... I am just saying.

Comment: @SpaceDog well, you can't possibly detect the crossing before the last sample since that's the sample on which the zero is finally crossed in the diginal signal. It's impossible to figure out on which time point of original signal the zero would have been crossed. I guess the best quess would be the middle zero, but in order to figure out whether you're currently at a middle zero, you must keep track of the index of the last non-zero sample and look ahead for the next crossing which requires buffering the signal.

Comment: Why is this method better than the accepted answer?